# Adding sata power to USB PCIe card causes shutdown to restart instead

Tags: usb, shutdown

Kernel: Ubuntu 22.04
MB: Supermicro H11DSI
USB PCI3: Fresco Logic 1100

I was able to shutdown properly when sata was disconnected. I'm new to Linux so I don't know how to debug this. Any help would be great.

Cheers,
Josh